# getHours() at 9pm returns 20, then after DST returns 21. How to always return the same number

Tags: javascript

I'm running code in the backend of google sheets, and I have a function on an every minute timer that then determines if it's the right time for it to run. I need it ran at precise times. I had it working properly to trigger at 9:05pm, but now that daylight savings has passed it's triggering at 8:05pm.

How do I fix this without having to manually change the value after every DST change? Is there a way for getHours() to return the same number at the same time throughout the year?

Answer (score 1):

[getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) is probably a better bet if you want consistency as there will be no DST.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) to get a consistent number of hours without concern for daylight savings time.

It depends on what you mean by consistent. If you're not looking for the same time each day in local time but for the event to happen ever 24 hours then I suggesting using UTC time.

```js
var halloweenNight = new Date('October 31, 2019, 21:00:00 EDT')
var thanksgivingNight = new Date('November 28, 2019, 20:00:00 EST')

console.log('Halloween EDT: ' + halloweenNight.toString())
console.log('Thanksgiving EST: ' + thanksgivingNight.toString())

console.log('Halloween UTC: ' + halloweenNight.toUTCString())
console.log('Thanksgiving UTC: ' + thanksgivingNight.toUTCString())

console.log('Halloween local hours: ' + halloweenNight.getHours())
console.log('Thanksgiving local hours: ' + thanksgivingNight.getHours())

console.log('Halloween UTC hours: ' + halloweenNight.getUTCHours())
console.log('Thanksgiving UTC hours: ' + thanksgivingNight.getUTCHours())
```